# При реализации паттерна абстрактная фабрика, выдает ошибку

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, шаблоны-проектирования, абстрактная-фабрика

```
#include <iostream>


// Animals ---------------------------------------

// Herbivores

class Herbivore abstract
{
protected:
    int weight;
    bool life;

public:
    virtual std::string animal() const = 0;
    virtual void eat_grass() = 0;
    virtual int getWeight() const = 0;
    virtual void printAnimal() const = 0;
};


class Wildebeest : public Herbivore
{
public:
    Wildebeest() : Herbivore()
    {
        this->weight = 150;
        this->life = true;
    }

    std::string animal() const override
    {
        return "Wildebeest";
    }

    void eat_grass() override
    {
        weight += 10;
    }

    int getWeight() const override
    {
        return weight;
    }

    void printAnimal() const override
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << animal() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t weight - " << weight << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t life - " << life << std::endl;
    }

};


class Bison : public Herbivore
{
public:
    Bison() : Herbivore()
    {
        this->weight = 400;
        this->life = true;
    }

    std::string animal() const override
    {
        return "Bison";
    }

    void eat_grass() override
    {
        weight += 10;
    }

    int getWeight() const override
    {
        return weight;
    }

    void printAnimal() const override
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << animal() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t weight - " << weight << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t life - " << life << std::endl;
    }
};


// Predators

class Predator abstract
{
protected:
    int power;

public:
    virtual std::string animal() const = 0;
    virtual void eat(Herbivore animal) = 0;
    virtual void printAnimal() const = 0;
};


class Lion : public Predator
{
public:
    Lion() : Predator()
    {
        this->power = 200;
    }

    std::string animal() const override
    {
        return "Lion";
    }

    void eat(Herbivore animal) override
    {
        power > animal.getWeight() ? power += 10 : power -= 10;
    }

    void printAnimal() const override
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << animal() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t power - " << power << std::endl;
    }
};


class Wolf : public Predator
{
public:
    Wolf() : Predator()
    {
        this->power = 170;
    }

    std::string animal() const override
    {
        return "Wolf";
    }

    void eat(Herbivore animal) override
    {
        power > animal.getWeight() ? power += 10 : power -= 10;
    }

    void printAnimal() const override
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << animal() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\t power - " << power << std::endl;
    }
};

// Continent -------------------------------------
class Continent abstract
{
public:

    virtual Herbivore* createWildebeest() const = 0;
    virtual Predator* createPredator() const = 0;
};


class Africa : public Continent
{
public:


    Herbivore* createWildebeest() const override
    {
        return new Wildebeest();
    }

    Predator* createPredator() const override
    {
        return new Lion();
    }
};


class NorthAmerica : public Continent
{
public:


    Herbivore* createWildebeest() const override
    {
        return new Bison();
    }

    Predator* createPredator() const override
    {
        return new Wolf();
    }
};

// Animals World----------------------------------

void AnimalsWorld(const Continent& continent)
{
    const Lion* lion = continent.createPredator();
}
```

Ошибку выдает в строке `const Lion* lion = continent.createPredator();`

выглядит она так - значение типа "Predator *" нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа "const Lion *"

Answer (score 3):

Начнем с того, что вы не имеете права использовать `void eat(Herbivore animal)` — это же абстрактный класс, только ссылка/указатель, но не объект абстрактного класса. Да и даже будь это не абстрактный класс — весь полиморфизм при этом просто умирает.

Далее, вы пытаетесь указатель на *базовый* класс (`Predator`) присвоить указателю на *производный* (`Lion`), а это делать неявно не разрешается.

Если вы уверены, что `continent.createPredator()` создает именно `Lion` (а это в общем случае не так!), то следует выполнить явное приведение типа

```
const Lion* lion = dynamic_cast<const Lion*>(continent.createPredator());
```

с *обязательной проверкой*, что получилось — не вернулся ли `nullptr` (на случай, если вас подвела ваша уверенность...).